# Get Value of textbox as field name in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

basically, I want to  have the value of my combobox1 as a field name of my query  below. can somebody help me here?

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase("\\location\file.mdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from customerinfo " _
  & "where '"& (combobox1.text) &"' likE '*" & (txtsearch) & "*';")

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Item Found"
Else
    Do While Not rs.EOF = True
        listbox.AddItem

        On Error Resume Next
        listbox.List(listbox.ListCount - 1, 0) = rs("Fieldname").Value

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
end if
```

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` this line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Remove it and fix your errors, tell which error you get and in which line.

Comment: I remove it and its still no error. it keeps on showing the msgbox and it seems  it cannot find any record from the database with that criteria.

Comment: I manually check and search on my access database and found the criteria that im trying to look using this code.i really dont know what seems wrong with these code. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your query:

```
where '"& (combobox1.text) &"' likE
```

This creates an incorrect where clause, `where 'fieldname' likE`, which should be
 `where fieldname likeE`. Change the query to:

```
where "& (combobox1.text) &" likE
```

Note: It is best to create the query string in a variable. That makes it easier to spot any errors.